# Multiple create of one model in single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller

Hello I am building ROR Survey application for survey. I am having a problem of saving multiple objects into my database.My paramters after submission look all good but instead get an error of:

**`undefined method`permit' for #Array:0x00007ff29d873010`**

My parameters look like

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"vdUPSIU43ex1Wx3qZB4Xr6qNEaG0FbEyK2tkJ9OCcAtxK3jHe5lKVohS9JFOdpx/cISwIvzAKTRGw5zxUUS4QA==", 
  "survey_response"=>[
    {"user_id"=>"1", "survey_question_id"=>"22", "answer"=>"Hello"}, 
    {"user_id"=>"1", "survey_question_id"=>"23", "answer"=>"Hello"}], 
  "commit"=>"Create Survey response"
}
```

My survey_response_params methods is

```
def survey_response_params
  params.require(:survey_response).permit(:answer, :survey_question_id, :user_id, :survey_answer_id)
end
```

My controller looks like :

```
class SurveyResponsesController < ApplicationController

def index
@survey_responses = SurveyResponse.all
end

def show
end

def new
@survey_response = SurveyResponse.new
@survey = Survey.find(1)
@survey_questions = @survey.survey_questions
end

def edit
@survey = Survey.find(1)
@survey_questions = @survey.survey_questions
end

def create
@survey_response = SurveyResponse.new(survey_response_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @survey_response.save
    format.html { redirect_to @survey_response, notice: 'Survey response was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @survey_response }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @survey_response.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @survey_response.update(survey_response_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @survey_response, notice: 'Survey response was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @survey_response }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @survey_response.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def destroy
@survey_response.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to survey_responses_url, notice: 'Survey response was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_survey_response
  @survey_response = SurveyResponse.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def survey_response_params
  params.permit(survey_response: [:answer, :survey_question_id, :user_id, :survey_answer_id])
end
end
```

Model

```
class SurveyResponse < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :survey_question
belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: why I dont use strong params: https://medium.com/@apneadiving/why-i-do-not-use-strong-parameters-in-rails-e3bd07fcda1d

Comment: Can you explain me how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your strong params, for array it looks like:

```
def survey_response_params
  params.permit(survey_response: [:answer, :survey_question_id, :user_id, :survey_answer_id])
end
```

UPDATE:

I don't know anything about your models and controller, but I think it should be something like this in the controller

```
survey_response_params[:survey_response].each do |attrs|
  SurveyResponse.new(attrs)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Vasilisa, on updating your answer I get error on `@survey_response = SurveyResponse.new(survey_response_params)` stating unknown attribute 'survey_response' for SurveyResponse.

Comment: @JoeDoe, I updated an answer. If you want to create multiple records you need to loop through 'survey_response' array in params

Comment: Hello Vasilisa I have added my controller to the question. Not sure where to loop survey params.

Comment: @JoeDoe, so many questions to you after update... What is you models structure? Does SurveyResponse belongs_to survey? Why do you want to create many responses at once and on which page you want to create them? If you want to create many - why you define only one in the new action? If you want to create survey with responses at once you need to read about [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Hello @Vasilisa, all I want to do is create all records at one. I have updated the model above